# How to query a view using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I query an existing table with the following code:

```
class Minicomputer(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables[' minicomputer']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Masterlist %r>' % self.Hostname
```

`Minicomputer.query.filter_by(name='CJ_1').first()` returns the result, now I want to query via an existing view named `mast_list`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to pass the name as an argument to the view and query?

Like this:

```
@app.route('/master/<string:name>')
def mast_list(name):
 return Minicomputer.query.filter_by(name=name).first()
```

Comment: it's a view use CREATE VIEW not a table